# Прочитать "закодированный" текст из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый файл с содержимым типа:
    name=\x22\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA0\xD0\x90\xD0\x9D\x22

Подскажите, как преобразовать эту строку в строку вида name="КРАН" ?

```
str = b'name=\x22\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA0\xD0\x90\xD0\x9D\x22'
print(str.decode("utf-8"))
```

такой код работает. А вот при чтении из файла преобразование не получается.

```
def test():
    inputfile = 'test.txt'
    i = 0
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            i += 1
            print(i, ":", line)
            print(i, ":", line.encode())

    str = b'name=\x22\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA0\xD0\x90\xD0\x9D\x22'
    print(str.decode("utf-8"))
```

Python 3.x

Upd:
В конечном результате хотелось бы получить примитивный конвертер для преобразования файла в удобочитаемый вид.

```
def test():
    outputfile = 'test_out.txt'
    inputfile = 'test.txt'
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as ofile:
        with open(inputfile, 'rb') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                res = line.decode('utf-8')
                print(res, file=ofile)
```

как-то так... Но не могу разобраться с преобразованиями

Comment: а в чем собственно вопрос? Ваш код `str.decode("utf-8")` - преобразует строку к `'name="КРАН"'`. Можете привести содержимое файла как есть?

Comment: Содержимое файла предельно простое, одна строка: name=\x22\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA0\xD0\x90\xD0\x9D\x22

Comment: какая кодировка у файла? и как вы получили данный файл? проще будет исправить проблему при создании файла...

Comment: utf-8 (пробовал и cp1251, картина не меняется)
на содержимое файла влиять не могу

Comment: вы можете выложить ваш файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8bs9cq34z8axv6/test.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вызвана неправильной сериализацией (сохранением) байт-строки или неправильным кодированием (`encode()`) строки.

Если у вас нет возможности исправить эту проблему в момент сохранения файла, то придётся использовать "костыли":

```
import codecs

with open(r'C:\download\test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

res = codecs.escape_decode(datab)[0].decode('utf-8')
print(res)
```

результат:

```
name="КРАН"
```

Comment: Блин, codecs.escape_decode пробовал, но не довёл до конца ))) Спасибо!

Comment: @Andrii, возможно есть менее кривое решение... Было бы проще если бы получилось воссоздать такой файл - вы не знаете каким кодом данный файл создается?

Comment: Нет, не знаю. Оригинальный файл - это лог какой-то системы. И таким образом похоже они кодируют кириллицу, чтобы на выходе не зависеть от кодировки (866, 1251, utf...) в которой будет открываться файл

Answer (score 0):

А если явно указать кодировку при открытии файла?
Ну что-то вроде такого:

```
def read_escunicode_file(inputfile):

    with open(inputfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        content = infile.read()

    content = content.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')

    return content

content = read_escunicode_file('test.txt')
print(content)
```

О самом open в [доке питона](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) лучше ещё почитать

Comment: Пробовал. Результат не меняется.

Comment: Быть не может, значит что-то не так с настройкой окружения или файлом. Надо вопрос дополнить точной версией питона, ОС и информацией о кодировке файла.

Comment: Кодировка файла в данном случае (мне так кажется) слабо влияет. Ссылку на файл выкладывал чуть выше в комментариях, можно посмотреть.

Comment: Ой сейчас. Напишу. Задача не очень очевидна была сначала.

Comment: Обновил код - должно работать. Но странное конечно.
Пример для файла с текстом "\x22\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA0\xD0\x90\xD0\x9D\x22"